# tdate issue I'm facing in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

While fetching count from table by using following query

```
Select count(*)  
from tab 
where tdate = '17-05-19' ---> output 0
```

or

```
Select count(*)  
from tab 
where trunc(tdate) = '17-05-19'  ---->output 0
```

If I use:

```
Select count(*)  
from tab 
where tdate  >sysdate - 1   ---> it returns some count(yesterday+some of the today txn)
```

But here I want only yesterday txn whenever I fire this query.

Comment: Hey Pravin, do you want the previous working day date or just the previous day date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But here I want only yesterday txn whenever I fire this query.

You may use this.

```
Select count (*) from tab where
         tdate >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1 
     AND tdate <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

The advantage of this over using `TRUNC` on the date column is that it will utilize an index if it exists over `tdate`

Answer (score 0):

If you tried by using

`Select count(*) from tab where trunc(tdate) = date'2019-05-17'`

(*or, you could use 
`Select count(*) from tab where to_char(tdate,'dd-mm-yy') = '17-05-19'` by formatting through `to_char`* *function*

*or, you could use 
`Select count(*) from tab where trunc(tdate) = trunc(sysdate)-1`* *to get only the data for the day before*
 )

you'd get some results provided you have data for the date 17th May.

So, you need to provide a formatting for your literal as `date'2019-05-17'`(known as *date literal*) especially for Oracle DB, it might be used as `'2019-05-17'` without `date` part in MySQL as an example.

Btw, `trunc` function is used to extract the date portion, and remove the time part of a `date` type column value.

If your table is populated with huge data, therefore performance may matter, then you can even create  functional index on `trunc(tdate)`.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6b49b2e4235c6bbae2d21b0b841e2259)</kbd>

Comment: I want to schedule this query on daily basis  without entering date on daily basis like sysdate-1 etc,  so please suggest by using sysdate or any other options

Comment: @PravinGaddam first of all, use also `sysdate` with `trunc` as `trunc(sysdate)-1`. Just consider the demo, without truncating sysdate you may encounter some problems. e.g if I omit trunc, sysdate-1 wouldn't cover the date yesterday as a whole. Some value would be included, some of them would be excluded because of different time values.

Comment: Here I'm trying with select  * from tab where tdate=trunc(sysdate) -1 ----> this output giving me (yesterday+today txn)

Comment: but on the 4th paragraph I told you consider `...where trunc(tdate) = trunc(sysdate)-1` which give yesterday only.